# Generate Access Token from JWT

Tags: jwt, google-cloud-storage, google-oauth

I am developing micro services on Google Cloud that take the JWT of the logged in user in their Authorization request header. Somewhere, down the line, I need to generate an access token from the JWT - like say to create a Storage object with the user`s credentials. How can I generate an access token from the JWT token ?

Comment: What kind of token are you wanting as an access token? Another JWT created from the JWT you have or encrypting the JWT and using the encryption as the access token? Etc.

Comment: I need to generate a "ya29.." token from the JWT . Any user token using which I can create a GoogleCredentials object

Comment: I tried posting {"grant_type":"urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer","assertion": "jwt"} to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token , but it gives me "The OAuth client was not found" error

Comment: Thanks, I was missing that step. I created a service account and used it as the issuer. After doing that , I get :  "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested." . Does this mean that I need to do the steps on Gsuite (as mentioned in the link you sent) ?

Comment: @PawelCzuczwara The github link you provided is using another token endpoint versus the one the OP is asking about.

Comment: @identigral - like PawelCzuczwara suggested, pls post your comment as the answer. I am yet to try it out, as I am not a Gsuite admin , but i think it is the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually means it can't find a service account based on the iss(uer) claim in the token. Did you create and authorize a service account and reference it in the JWT?

Comment: I am posting this , for the benefit of any others facing the same problem . This link here: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/ , explains with a code sample on how we can get an access token for a user using a service account. Though, its not exactly what I was looking for, this seems to be the only way out on GCP . Do remember that for this to work, your service account must be added to your gsuite domain and authorized for the scope you are trying to create the access token with.